# error while archiving with Build Configuration in schema settings to 'App Store'

Tags: ios, xcode, build, publish, archive

I'm facing weird error in Xcode 7.3.
when I'm trying to archive with schema settings "Release", it works successfully. but problem occurs when I change Build Configuration to 'App Store'
.
Menu > Product > Schema > Edit Schema > Archive > Build Configuration : App Store.

I don't know what exactly problem is, but when I choose 'Release' in option then it works fine for me.

It also shows #import "Project/Project-Swift.h" file not found while archiving for App Store only.
I think it gives error related to bridging header between Swift and Objective-C.
Please help, if anybody know the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no App Store scheme by default, you must have added it and you should check out the difference in build settings for it

Comment: Please show the error message you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but finally, I got solution now. I added 'App Store' configuration in SDK project.